# Does GLSL's mix() clamp the third parameter?

Tags: opengl, glsl, interpolation, linear-interpolation

Does GLSL's mix() clamp the third parameter to the [0, 1] range before using it to interpolate before the other two?

I could write a shader to test this, but: I don't want to just test my particular implementation of GLSL, and also it'd be nice to have an answer to this available online for a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My reading of the GLSL spec is that no clamping is done:

> Returns the linear blend of x and y, i.e., x⋅(1 − a) + y⋅a

(https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf)